# How to remove the maximize button from Caliburn Windows Manager Dialog

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using the Caliburn Micro Window Manager to display a dialog. I would like to remove the maximize and minimize buttons from the dialog.

If I look at the Windows Manager source (under WPF) I can see a third parameter that lets me pass settings to the dialog. My problem is that I can't pass a third parameter - I get an error. This can be replicated in the hello window manager example project.

Any ideas?

Somehow I seem to be referencing an IWindowManager that only allows 2 parameters to ShowDialog.

This is what I want to do but causes an error:

```
var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();

WindowManager windowManager = new WindowManager();

Dictionary<string, object> settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();

// add settings here to pass to dialog

windowManager.ShowDialog(loginViewModel, null, settings);
```

This is IWindowManager interface that shows 3 parameters:

```
public interface IWindowManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a modal dialog for the specified model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootModel">The root model.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="settings">The optional dialog settings.</param>
    /// <returns>The dialog result.</returns>
    bool? ShowDialog(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a non-modal window for the specified model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootModel">The root model.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="settings">The optional window settings.</param>
    void ShowWindow(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a popup at the current mouse position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootModel">The root model.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The view context.</param>
    /// <param name="settings">The optional popup settings.</param>
    void ShowPopup(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);
}
```

Comment: Please show some code, for those of us not intimately familiar with Caliburn Micro's implementation details. :)

Comment: Have added code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall any recent version of Caliburn.Micro that used IWindowManager.ShowDialog with three parameters. Are you maybe referring to [this link from the Codeplex site](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/154)? It appears to be a user request that Rob rejected.

As you probably know, ShowDialog() will cause the IWindowManager to instantiate a view it finds (by naming convention) and attach it to whatever viewmodel you provide it (e.g. LoginViewModel is attached to a "found" view called LoginView).

I'm guessing that LoginView is a UserControl for you, but you can have this view be a regular Window and then set the WindowStyle property (in XAML) to use one of the options that does not have the maximize button. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) shows the various enumeration options. WindowStyle.ToolWindow is the only one that includes the close button and not the min/max buttons, but because it changes the appearance of the close button, you may prefer WindowStyle.None and just define your own window chrome and buttons.

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.LoginView"
        ...
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: The example code I added to my question was taken from Caliburn v1.2 source and shows IWindowManager.ShowDialog with 3 parameters. Caliburn uses the third parameter to set properties of the window. However even in the HelloWindowManager example I can't set the third parameter so must be somehow using a different interface. Very puzzling. Thanks for your suggestion - I'll give it a try.

Comment: I see what you're referring to now for "ShowPopup" but the method signature is not there for ShowDialog. Even with ShowPopup I'm not sure how it would work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The method signature for ShowDialog in the code example I provided has 3 parameters.

Comment: Right, but using Caliburn.Micro RTW 1.2, the IWindowManger interface does not use the same signatures you have quoted in your post for ShowDialog() and ShowWindow().

Comment: Was looking at v1.3 source - 3rd parameter is there. Removed Nuget package, manually installed v1.3 and all works.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Good to hear.

Answer (score 4):

```
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
            settings.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
            settings.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            settings.Title = "Test";

windowManager.ShowDialog(loginViewModel, "Modeless", settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your View as Usercontrol make it a **Window** and set its **ResizeMode="NoResize"**

```
<Window x:Class="Company.Project.Views.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

Now you will only have red "X" close button and no maximize/minimize buttons.